# How to layout HTML 5 using DIVs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn html 5, I am trying to reproduce the rules to my current favourite game Camel Up (or Camel Cup) and am trying to be a good person and not just use a table, this is what i am trying to achieve
[image: what i want to produce]

this is what i am getting
[image]

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CamelCup Rules</title>
        <style>
            body {background-color:#f3d7a0; font-family:cursive}
            #wrapper {width:1000px}
            .float-left { float:left;width:40%;padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px;}
            .float-right {float:right;width:40%;padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px;}
            #banner-text{ font-size: smaller;}
            .red-label {font-size:medium; color:red;vertical-align:top}
            h1 {color:red; text-align: center; font-size:40px}
            .full-width {width="100%";}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
            <div class="full-width">
                <div id="logo" class="float-left">
                    <img src="logo.PNG">
                </div>
                <div id="banner-text" class="float-right">
                    <p>
                    Witness the craziest camel race of all time, as things really go topsy-turvy when
    camels stack up and entire pyramids turn upside down.
    As members of Egyptian high society, you gather in the desert with one simple
    goal: to gain the most money by backing the right camel to win a leg or even the
    entire race. However, in this race, it’s not just the lucky ones who can beat the
    odds. Reading the dynamics of the race and having a good sense of timing is just as
    important when it comes to backing the right camels and taking the victory.
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section id="contents" class="full-width">
                <h1>Components</h1>
                <div id="pyramid" class="float-left">
                    <label class="red-label">1 Pyramid</label>
                    <img src="pyramid.png">
                </div>
            </section>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if I make it variable width and enlarge my browser it looks like this (this is in response to an answer telling me to make it variable width but i can't see where to add pictures to comments)
[image]

Comment: So what is the issue? It looks correct based off of your image? Or not?

Comment: the components div is centered underneath the logo and not underneath both the logo and the banner.  Neither the logo or banner are 50% of the width, thre is about a 5cm gap between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This is what you want?]

Make these Changes:

1. Remove "" from .full-width

   .full-width {width: 100%;}
2. Add this styling

   #contents{clear:both;}
3. Also change width of #wrappper from 1000px to 100%

## wrapper {width:100%;}

Comment: the wrapper is at 1000px as I want a fixed width page, everything just went horribly wrong every time i resized the window.  Will have to read what {clear:both} does as it seems very important

Comment: The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float. You can give values of left, right and both to it.

Comment: I presumed the width 100% would do that, saying I want this to take up the full width, but it was just overlapping the text.  I have added a picture to explain the variable width issue

Comment: Ok change the width to whatever size you want to. Just apply the clear:both; and you should be getting what you need?

Comment: yep the clear:both did it, thanks. I have added it to the full-width class, as that is what i want when i call something full width.

Answer (score 2):

This rule has an error in it:

```
.full-width {width="100%";}
```

should be

```
.full-width {width: 100%;}
```